# Как найти площадь полигона в GoogleMaps?

Tags: алгоритм, google-maps-api, javascript

Как известно, в картах гугль фигуры, в частности, полигон, задаются набором геокоординат (широта и долгота).
Много есть простых алгоритмов вычисления площади полигона по декартовым координатам, а встречались ли вам алгоритмы или готовые модули для вычисления площади полигона, заданного набором геокоординат?..

Comment: Копай в сторону сферической геометрии. Гео-координаты широта и долгота это полярные координаты на сфере или, по простому, углы. [Здесь][1] описано как посчитать площадь треугольника на сфере с вершинами  заданными полярными координатами. А полигон - это, по сути, несколько треугольников.

  [1]: http://www.astronet.ru/db/msg/1190817/node7.html

Comment: по ссылке - это все мне известно. теория. ищу реализацию.
мне понравился алгоритм С.Б.Калачовой, но он для плоских координат

Comment: Кстати, в v2 у объекта `GPolygon` есть метод [`getArea()`][1]. Он возвращает площадь многоугольника в квадратных метрах. В v3 ничего подобного не увидел :(.

  [1]: http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GPolygon.getArea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

итак, внимание:
 1. подключаем библиотеку геометрий гугль:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

2.получаем массив значений пар координат полигона, площадь которого нужно вычислить (в моем случае я читаю их из некоторого заранее подготовленного массива zones):

```
    for(k=0;k<zones[2].length;k++) {
    var currentcoord=new google.maps.LatLng(zones[2][k][0],zones[2][k][1]);
    currzonecoords.push(currentcoord);
    }
```

3.собственно производим вычисление, используя функцию из вышеподключенной гугле-либрари:

```
var zonearea = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(currzonecoords);
```

и таки в квадратных метрах!..

ЗЫЖ: ссылка на методы гуглевской геометрической библиотеки: http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#spherical

Comment: Отличная находка. По идее, можно еще немного упростить. Если есть готовый объект полигона, то у него есть метод getPath(). Вроде как он возвращает массив вершин полигона.

Comment: кстати, хочу поблагодарить именно KiTE за наводку -- так бы я и не вспомнил, что у гугля есть геометрические библиотеки