# Помогите найти площадь полигона в GoogleMaps?

Tags: google-maps-api

Объясните как найти площадь и показать его при нажатии на полигон?
У меня он не работает этот код

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
<script>
function initMap() {
var element = document.getElementById('map');
var options = {
zoom: 8,
center: {lat: 40.40926, lng: 49.86709},
};
var myMap = new google.maps.Map(element, options);
var Baku = new google.maps.LatLng(40.40926,49.86709);
var Sabirabad = new google.maps.LatLng(40.00869,48.47701); 
var Agsu = new google.maps.LatLng(40.5694, 48.3999);
var Xizi = new google.maps.LatLng(40.907778, 49.073333);
var Sumqayit = new google.maps.LatLng(40.58548,49.63174);
var myTrip = [Baku, Sabirabad, Agsu, Xizi, Sumqayit];
var markers = [
{
coordinates: {lat: 40.40926, lng: 49.86709},
info: 'Baku'
},
{coordinates: {lat: 40.00869, lng: 48.47701},
info: 'Sabirabad'
},
{
coordinates: {lat: 40.5694, lng: 48.3999},
info: 'Agsu'
},
{
coordinates: {lat: 40.907778, lng: 49.073333},
info: 'Xizi'
},
{
coordinates: {lat: 40.58548, lng: 49.63174},
info: 'Sumqayit'
}
];
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
addMarker(markers[i]);
}
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polygon({
path:myTrip,
strokeColor:"#0000FF",
strokeOpacity:1,
strokeWeight:2,
fillColor:"#0000FF",
fillOpacity:0.3
});
flightPath.setMap(myMap);
for(k=0;k<myTrip[2].length;k++) {
var currentcoord=new google.maps.LatLng(myTrip[2][k][0],myTrip[2][k][1]);
currzonecoords.push(currentcoord);
}
var zonearea = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(currzonecoords);
function addMarker(properties) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: properties.coordinates,
map: myMap,
animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
});
if(properties.info) {
var InfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: properties.info
});
marker.addListener('click', function(){
InfoWindow.open(myMap, marker);
});
}
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: вам же ответили как найти площадь. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/67596/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-googlemaps/1173662#1173662

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как найти площадь полигона в GoogleMaps?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/67596/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-googlemaps)